# Как сделать ENUM ENUM'ов?

Tags: java, enum, enum-class

Значит у меня есть БД таблицы в которых есть столбцы которые содержат  ENUM значения. Для генерации запросов из Java я хотел "зафиксировать" возможные передаваемые значения в SQL запрос. Т.е. примерно это должно выглядеть вот так `Tables.TABLES.SEASON.MONTH.APRIL.name()`. Как это возможно реализовать, если вообще возможно? Можно ли внутрь ENUM вкладывать несколько других классов ENUM?

Answer (score 1):

Это все что я смог:

```
public class Enums {
    
    public enum MONTH2 {
        APRIL,
        APRIL2;
    }
    
    public enum TABLES {
        

        SEASON (MONTH2.values());

        
        private TABLES(final MONTH2[] mm) { 
            MONTH = mm[0];
        }
        
        public MONTH2 MONTH;
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(TABLES.SEASON.MONTH.APRIL.name());  // В консоли будет APRIL
        System.out.println(TABLES.SEASON.MONTH.APRIL2.name());  // В консоли будет APRIL2
    }
}
```

PS: есть еще класс [java.lang.Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html), может он поможет?